# Installing MS SQL Server on Debian 11 -- Repo Signature Problem

Tags: debian, ubuntu, repository, gpg, sqlserver

trying install MS SQL Server 2022 on Debian 11 is driving me crazy, as I'm not being able to add MS repo properly.
First of all, step-by-step guide by Microsoft -just for Ubuntu- in this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-ver16&preserve-view=true

I add the the repo and import the public key, but doing sudo apt-get update gives the following error:

`GPG Error: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022 focal InRelease: the following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF`

I try importing again, but this time using gpg, importing the public key:

`gpg --recv-keys --keyserver https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc EB3E94ADBE1229CF`

The key was added, I even check it with Kleopatra an the public key is imported.

But then again, doing sudo apt-get update, I get the same error again!

`GPG Error: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022 focal InRelease: the following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF`

I don't understand why apt-get cannot find the public key, if it is correctly imported.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Unix! You can improve your question by converting the URL to a link with an alternate string so screen readers will not speak the whole URL.

Answer (score 2):

`apt` uses `gpg`, but it maintains its own keyring store in `/etc/apt/keyrings` rather than the default `~/.gnupg/`.

`apt-key` (a wrapper around gpg specifically for apt's needs) is the tool for manipulating apt's key store.

[Microsoft's own web page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/linux-package-repository-for-microsoft-software) has instructions for importing the key into apt with `apt-key add`:

```
curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod
sudo apt-get update
```

That will need to be edited slightly for Debian 11 rather than 10.  Or for whichever Ubuntu release you're using (don't use Debian packages with Ubuntu and vice-versa.  The .deb format is compatible, but the actual packages and the libraries they depend upon may not be - and usually aren't).

And even the page you linked to has something very similar:

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

(whether you use `curl` or `wget` to download the key is irrelevant - it's the `apt-key add` that's important)

---

PS: If you don't have any specific need for MS SQL (e.g. as a learning/training exercise or you use other software that ONLY works with it and not other SQL databases), IMO you would be far better off using [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/) instead.  It's packaged for Debian and almost every other Linux distro.

Comment: if you won't mind - please update the apt-key  add since it has been deprecated to usr/share/keyrings